# Script to remote login into server

Tags: shell, login, remote

I am using Ubuntu bash. I want to remote login to server through shell, it will give me its own command line. Then enter 'shell' followed by login credential again followed by a command. I need that command output printed on my screen. Please suggest, how do I do that?

Comment: I think you may be looking for the `ssh` command?  To log into a remote machine you can do: `ssh [user]@[hostname|ip address]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh HOSTNAME "run_command with arguments"
```

will execute the command **run_command** and pass it two arguments - 1: "with" and 2: "arguments" ;-)
OUTPUT will go to stdout .. as usual
So if you want to check the files in a directory for *evil* stuff, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=my-server.biz
check="/opt/path/to/check"
list=`ssh $host "ls $check"`
evil=`echo -e "$list"|grep -c "evil"`
if [ $evil -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "all is well"
else
  echo "the end is nigh"
fi
```